# How to split a social graph (on matrix form)?

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, linear-algebra

I have a undirected binary social graph represented as a `2d numpy array`, e.g. like the picture below.
I want to split this matrix into two, based on a binary indicator vector.

For example if I have the graph corresponding to the image below and the indicator vector `[0,1,1,0,1]` I want `[2,3,5]` in one group, and `[1,4]` in another, thus giving me a `3x3` and a `2x2` matrix.

I can't seem to figure out which permutations to perform/slices to take.
Any suggestions?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't all that difficult with [numpy indexing](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/arrays.indexing.html):

Here is a sample matrix:

```
np.random.seed(0)
m = np.random.randint(0, 10, (5, 5))
print(m)

[[5 0 3 3 7]
 [9 3 5 2 4]
 [7 6 8 8 1]
 [6 7 7 8 1]
 [5 9 8 9 4]]
```

Then to get the relevant groups out of your indicator vector:

```
indicator = np.array([0,1,1,0,1])
group1 = np.where(indicator == 0)[0] # [0 3]
group2 = np.where(indicator == 1)[0] # [1 2 4]
```

And finally, to get the relevant columns and rows for each:

```
>>> m[group1, :][:, group1]
[[5 3]
 [6 8]]
>>> m[group2, :][:, group2]
[[3 5 4]
 [6 8 1]
 [9 8 4]]
```